# How to remove freeze webpage after closing the swal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here I am closing the form after form gets submitted successfully with all required fields .
But inside that submit function there is Swal (alert) for confirmation . But after clicking on swal OK button my webpage gets freeze and didn't respond

```
const handleCloseModal = () => {            
    document.getElementById("modalid").classList.remove("show","d-block");
    document.querySelectorAll(".modal-backdrop").forEach(el => el.classList.remove("modal-backdrop"));
  }
```

added this function inside the onSubmit function

Comment: please specify the swal alert version you used. there has 2 version https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/ and https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: "sweetalert": "^2.1.2" currently i am using 2.1.2